# SVN repositry restored & newer commits/updates on client

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

A clients with SVN commit other have the SVN updated the last revision say 66.

Now, my SVN server repository had to be restored from a backup, lets say from 11-Jan-2019. This means, the SVN repository has the last revision as say 65.

I am using latest Win Tortoise and the latest SVN release (SVNServer).

This means, some clients have newer data files as the restored SVN repository!

The question is now how to bring the client & server back on track.

From the SVN client log I have the commit file list. Those files I will copy to a separated place and would like to revert to revision 65, but the SVN client complains about: No such revision 66..

Or I have to checkout from the server to a new folder and update those saved files to the checkout folder and commit/add again?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better discard the working copies. Subversion is not designed to handle that situation gracefully. My suggestion:

1. Check out a fresh working copy at current HEAD (r65).
2. Use your favourite file compare tool to copy the appropriate changes from a r66 working copy and commit again.
3. To be sure (it may not be strictly necessary) discard the old r66 working copy and replace it with the other copy or simply check out again. Another possibility that may also work is to use the "Update to revision…" context menu to go back to r65 and then "SVN Update" again.

Comment: Yes, I have this feelings too, even to revisions may not have timestamps and this could very easy into a mess if one do not cleanup all client pc's ..

Comment: regarding reverting to revision: SVNTortoise complains on reverting to revision 65: No such revision 66!!